# javascript Math and css percentage

Tags: javascript, math, progress

I have a progress div container and an xhr request posting base64 images to the server.

The progress indicator div looks as follows:

```
<style>
.progresscover {
 background: #eee;
 width:100%;
 height: 3px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 }
 .progress{
 width:0%;
 height:100%;
 background: purple;
 position:absolute:
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 bottom:0px;
  }
</style>
<div class="progresscover"><div class="progress"></div></div>
```

from the XHR request i get following values
loaded: 102533, total: 703227
The loaded obviously changes till its equal to the total..

what is the math to increase the width of the "progress" bar incrementally in percentages?

Comment: Divide loaded by total and multiply with the total width of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

its like this -- parseInt( (loaded / total * 100), 10) + '%');

Comment: What's the `parseInt()` for? These are already numbers.

Comment: Hi Thomas.. The parseInt() is a habit for me as ive had issues in the past where the normal math does and then does not work.. The parseInt() just ensure it works :)..

Comment: "habit" is a poor argument. "the normal math does and then does not work" sounds like sometimes you don't know the data types you're dealing with. `loaded / total * 100` will always return a number; even if it is `NaN`. But that's something parseInt won't fix for you! In your code, `parseInt` takes the number from your computation, converts it into a string *(because parseInt parses only strings)*, then parses that string back into a number *(just without the decimal places if there were any)* for you to then convert it back into a string by doing `+ '%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```js
function percentage(num1,num2){
    return (num1/num2) * 100
}
get = () =>{
    let value1 = document.getElementById('first').value; 
    let value2 = document.getElementById('second').value;
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = `<h2>the percentage is :` + percentage(value1,value2) + `% </h2>`;
    document.getElementById('file').value = percentage(value1,value2)

}
```

```css
    .a{
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .one{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .two{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .res{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    button {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 10px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
     }
```

```html
 <div>
    <div class="a">
      <div class="one">first Number :<input type="number" id="first"></div>
      <div class="two">second number :<input type="number" id="second"></div>
      <button onclick="get()">Get Percentage</button>
    </div>
    <div id="res"></div>
    <label for="file">Percentage:</label>

    <progress id="file" max="100" value=""> </progress>

  </div>
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach using the <progress> tag.. I did get my method to work though using the above answer. I never considered this approach.. Thank you for the insight.